# Formato de ventana modal con formulario

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Gente, buenas!!

Estoy intentando realizar una ventana modal con el siguiente formato con **bootstrap 4.6**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al realizar el código, la ventana se muestra de la siguiente manera y no entiendo por que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo la X de cerrar la ventana no queda con formato, las rows quedan todas juntas sin espacios...

Me podrán ayudar?

El código es el siguiente:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trackerModal"> 
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Proyecto
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="trackerModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="nuevoProyecto" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width: 75%;">
    <!--Con el min-width manejo el ancho del modal -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="nuevoProyecto">Nuevo Proyecto</h2>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <form>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="observaciones">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="fecha_ini">Fecha Inicio</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_ini" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="fecha_fin">Fecha Fin</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_fin">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="site">Site</label>
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="site" required>
                  <option selected>Elegir Site...</option>
                  <option value=""></option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.modal-body-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--.modal-content-->
  </div>
  <!--.modal-dialog-->
</div>
<!--.modal-->
```

Comment: prueba usar la clase "form-control" en vez de "form-group"

Comment: No, me lo destruye todo :(

Answer (score 0):

He corrido el código que pasaste y obtuve el mismo error. Lo que me percaté es que no estás enlazando las librerías CDN de la versión de bootstrap que estás utilizando.

*Dentro de tu etiqueta `<head>`:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

*Dentro de tu etiqueta `<body>` (justo debajo del código del modal):*

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Puedes ver los resultados en [este proyecto](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/ExEZXLr) que tengo preparado.

> Para evitar estos posibles errores en tus futuros proyectos, asegúrate
> ver la [guía de introducción](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) de la versión de Bootstrap que estés
> utilizando, comenzando por instalar los CDN y posteriormente el código
> que desees, saludos.